# TensorFlow Selecting entries (from one of two tensors) based on a boolean mask

Tags: tensorflow

I have three tensors, `a`, `b`, and `mask`, all of the same shape.  I'd like to produce a new tensor `c`, such that each entry of `c` is taken from the corresponding entry of `a` iff the corresponding entry of `mask` is True; else, it is taken from the corresponding entry of `b`.

Example:

```
a = [0, 1, 2]
b = [10, 20, 30]
mask = [True, False, True]
c = [0, 20, 2]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use `tf.select(condition, t, e, name=None)`

for your example:

```
c = tf.select(mask, a, b)
```

for more details about `tf.select`, visit [Tensorflow Control Flow Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#select)

Comment: Excellent! It seems like this is made for exactly what I want.

Comment: Note that `tf.select` has been renamed to `tf.where` from version 1.0 or so

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
1) convert mask to ints (0 for false, 1 for true)
2) do element wise multiplication of int_mask with tensor 'a' 
    (elements that should not be included are going to be 0)
3) do logical_not on mask
4) convert logical_not_int_mask to ints 
   (again 0 for false, 1 for true values)
5) now just do element wise multiplication of logical_not_int_mask with tensor 'b' 
   (elements that should not be included are going to be 0)
6) Add tensors 'a' and 'b' together and there you have it.
```

In code it should look something like this:

```
# tensor 'a' is [0, 1, 2]
# tensor 'b' is [10, 20, 30]
# tensor 'mask' is [True, False, True]

int_mask = tf.cast(mask, tf.int32)
# Leave only important elements in 'a'
a = tf.mul(a, int_mask) 
mask = tf.logical_not(mask)
int_mask = tf.cast(mask, tf.int32)
b = tf.mul(b, int_mask)
result = tf.add(a, b)
```

Or simply use tf.select() function just like someone already mentioned.